# Angular Directive not working when DOM updated

Tags: angularjs, materialize, dirpagination

I have following directive

```js
var app = angular.module('TestApp', []);
app.directive('selectMultiple', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      $(element).find('select').material_select();
      $(element).find("ul li").first().click(function() {
        $(element).find("ul li:not(:first-child)").each(function(index) {
          $(this).find("input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked", $(element).find("ul li").first().find("input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked"));
        });
      });
    }
  };
});
```

And I am also using dirpagination on same page, Its working , but when page changed, means DOM gets new elements, whatever written in directive is completely not working.

AM I missing any thing, I am new to angular so might be I'll be missing some things

Thanks

Comment: angular version?

Comment: angular version is 1.2.20

Comment: results for pagination from back end resp?

Comment: no, just updating the DOM, using dirpagination plugin

Comment: Directive is applied only once at the start. You have to include some sort of watch in your link function and rerun the code when it is triggered.

Comment: yes exactly , but I am new in angular so not able think of it, how to do it

Comment: please add the HTML snippet where you're attaching the directive.